# Azure Function app with knex not finishing

Tags: azure, nodes, azure-functions, knex.js

I created funnction app and service bus (with topic and its subscriptions), then added function (triggered by new message in topic's sub.). I wanted to write that message to DB (created that db and sql server for it - tried and i coudl connect with my local scripts and clients). Then, I added script's code into index.js in that new function:

```
module.exports = function(context, mySbMsg) {
    context.log('EVENT : ', mySbMsg);

    const dbConfig = {
        client: 'mssql',
        connection: {
            server: '---',
            user: '---',
            password: '---',
            options: {
                database: '---',
                port: 1433,
                encrypt: true
            }
        }
    }
    const knex = require('knex')(dbConfig);

    const newRow = {MessageRecived:mySbMsg}
    context.log('   New row : ', newRow);

    var res;
    return knex.insert(newRow).into('MyEvents').timeout(3000)
    .then((output)=>{
        context.log('       result : ');    
        context.log(output);    
        res = { status: 201, body: "Insert succeeded." };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        context.log('       error : '); 
        context.log(error); 
        res = { status: 500, body: "Error occured" };
    })
    .finally(() => {
        console.log('>> FINALLY');  
        knex.destroy(); 
        context.done(null, res);
    });
};
```

I dont understand why each request just "hangs" until Fucntion App itself decide it wont finsih, mark it as timeout and leaves. I thought it is becouse of knex, but I added "Destroy"... Still i don't know - Why isn't it working?

Comment: What logs do you see? Can you try running locally with the azure-functions-cli and capture network traffic?

Comment: Locally - there is no issues with this. Simply running and finishing itself. When run as function app, when triggered it simply won't finish (outside off 5 minutes time-out) and wont show any logs.